# emacs + rmarkdown not cross-referencing figures, tables, and equations

Tags: markdown

the example from https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html
does not work for me. I simply get references like "Figure @ref(fig:cars-plot)." appearing in the pdf or html document, i.e the raw markdown appears rather "Figure 1"
The code is below and the versions of installed packages are below that.
It seems to be an emacs problem. People have tried the attached code in Rstudio and
the references come out correctly.

```
---
title: Cross-referencing figures, tables, and equations
author: Generated by bookdown
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---
See Figure \@ref(fig:cars-plot).
```

```
par(mar = c(4, 4, .2, .1)) 
plot(cars)  # a scatterplot
```

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.8.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.0  magrittr_2.0.1  fastmap_1.1.0   tools_4.1.0    
 [5] htmltools_0.5.2 yaml_2.2.2      tinytex_0.36    stringi_1.7.6  
 [9] rmarkdown_2.11  highr_0.9       knitr_1.37      stringr_1.4.0  
[13] xfun_0.29       digest_0.6.29   rlang_0.4.12    evaluate_0.14  
``

and the pandoc command is

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test4.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test4.tex --lua-filter /home/dun280/local/lib/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.0/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /home/dun280/local/lib/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.0/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'
```

Comment: Sorry, I can see that the formatting has been mucked up. It seems that StackExchange allows some markdown formatting. I don't know how to format the code in my question without StackExchange interpreting it. However the link to rmarkdown-cookbook in the question goes to a properly formatted version of the code

Comment: The problem seems to be that the command "M-n e" which runs the command polymode-export sends the following to R
`
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = 'pdf_document', output_file = 'test.pdf', knit_root_dir=getwd())
`
rather than
`
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_document2', output_file = 'test.pdf', knit_root_dir=getwd())
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple. The first time a document is processed,
`M-n e` 
brings up the question
`choose exporter:` for which I set markdown-ess. Then it says
`export to:`.
The tab key brings up options. Choose "AUTO DETECT",
this will set the R command to something like

```
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_document2', output_file = 'test.pdf', knit_root_dir=getwd())
```

and the `output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_document2'` makes everything work.